# Appending string at the end of url in GET method :Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I am working with **volley** library in my android app development.

I have a base url and I need to append some value at the end of the url,[click here](http://www.sample.com/testing/ZGxb87HuJK),

So, this value "**ZGxb87HuJK**" keeps changing dynamically in my program and need to append this value at the end of url. How to add this in params?

Comment: check my answer its working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way.

```
 StringRequest strreq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
     "https://sample.com/testing/" + Hear Your dynamic value,
      new Response.Listener<String>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(String Response) {
                  // get response
         }
      }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
         @Override
         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
});
Volley.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(strreq);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String URL =  "https://sample.com/testing/" + "dynamic value e.g ZGxb87HuJK";

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
    URL, null,
    new Response.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            //Success Callback
        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //Failure Callback
        }
    });
// Adding the request to the queue along with a unique string tag
MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectReq, "getRequest");
```

Change your code like this